# Retrieve data from SQLite and showing the data as radio buttons

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, radio-button, android-sqlite

I'm developing an android application which stores words given by the user in a SQLite database. And I want to retrieve those words as radio buttons so that the user can select only one word from the words list show in the textview.
And I want to create the xml file to fulfill that requirement.
Help me with this and thanks in advance.

*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".EditPhrase">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="355dp"
    android:layout_height="71dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:text="@string/edit_phrases"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/phraseView"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/line_spacing"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_regular"
            android:text="" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

*

P.S. - "phraseView" textview is used to show the retrieved data from sqlite database and it works and all the words are printed one by one.

[image]

Now I want to have a radio button in-front of every word so that the user can select only one word

*

```
public class EditPhrase extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;
    DatabaseHelper translateDB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_phrase);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.phraseView);
        translateDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        showData();
    }


    public void showData(){
        Cursor cursor = translateDB.retrieveData();
        System.out.println("1");
        if (cursor.getCount() == 0){
            Toast.makeText(EditPhrase.this, "No data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        System.out.println("2");
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            System.out.println("3");
            buffer.append("     " + cursor.getString(0) + "\n");
        }

        textView.setText(buffer.toString());

    }

}
```

*

Comment: have you tried putting the radio buttons inside a recyclerView witch is inside a radioGroup?

Comment: not much familiar with recyclerView can you pls explain it

Comment: are you familiar with ListView? RecyclerView almost does the same job

Comment: yeah I solved the issue by using a list view , thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the radio buttons inside a `RecyclerView` or `ListView` which is inside a `RadioGroup`

Comment: I've used an array adapter and completed the task, by the way thank you for you time